# Renaming shapefiles and raster files with Python

Tags: python, shapefile

I'm trying to add "_Kiwi" to the name of multiple shapefiles and raster files in a folder C:\data.  For the files with multiple extensions (.shp.xml for example), I can't get the files to rename correctly.

My python script (in c:\data\renamefiles.py) is:

```
import glob 
import os
import sys

dirToProcess = sys.argv[1]
matchPattern = sys.argv[2]
replacePattern = sys.arg[3]

print "Processing " + dirToProcess

if (os.path.isdir(dirToProcess)):
    print dirToProcess + " found"
else:
    print dirToProcess + " not found"
    exit ()
print "continuing processing..."

def rename (dir, pattern, titlePattern):
    for pathAndFilename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir, pattern)):
        title, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pathAndFilename))
        print "found: " + title + "renaming..."
        os.rename(pathAndFilename, 
                           os.path.join(dir, titlePattern % title + ext))
```

---

The files with multiple extensions are not getting renamed correctly.  Here are two examples:

Example 1:   original files is: shapefile1.shp.xml

If I type....  python renamefiles.py c:\data *.shp.xml %s_KIWI, I end up with: shapefile1.shp_KIWI.xml

Example 2:  original file is: Raster1.sid.aux.xml

If I type python renamefiles.py c:\data *.sid.aux.xml %s_KIWI, I end up with: Raster1.sid.aux_KIWI.xml

How can I do this with only my current libraries/modules?

Comment: If you have access to arcpy (tagged as such) then you can use the Rename tool in the data management toolbox to do this. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000056000000

Comment: thank you so much dslamb. i don't have access to arcpy (or even arcmap) right now... but i will in the near future.  as soon as I do, i'll check out your link.  i really appreciate your comment and info - thank you!

Comment: I edited your tags to remove arcpy and arcgis desktop since you do not have access to either of these.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
import sys
import fnmatch

dirToProcess = sys.argv[1]
matchPattern = sys.argv[2]
replacePattern = sys.argv[3]

print "Processing " + dirToProcess

if (os.path.isdir(dirToProcess)):
    print "dir " + dirToProcess + " found"
else:
    print dirToProcess + " not found"
    exit ()
print "continuing processing..."


for filename in os.listdir(dirToProcess):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, matchPattern):
        print "found: " + filename + " renaming..."
        filename_base = filename.split('.')[0]
        extension = filename.split(filename_base)[1]
        new_name = (replacePattern + extension ) % filename_base
        os.rename(os.path.join(dirToProcess, filename),
                  os.path.join(dirToProcess, new_name))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [walk function](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000023000000) from the data access module and [Rename tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000056000000) from Data management. Refer to the help files for code samples